# In ubuntu, how to display directory using nginx?

Tags: nginx

I install nginx in Ubuntu server 12.04, and want to explore some dojo examples. I must go to some different directory and explore some html.

How can I display directory using nginx? Such as /usr/local/dojo/example. Then I can easily open these html example.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ngx_http_autoindex_module` (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) you can list all files in a specific directory.

An example of configuration :

```
location / {
    root /usr/local/dojo/example/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Then you will be able to click and load your examples.